# Is it true for every prime power $q$ that $q-1 | q^r - 1$?

Tags: arithmetic

Suppose $q$ is a prime power, $r$ is some positive integer. We can construct the field $\mathbb{F}_q$ where there are $q-1$ non-zero elements. The relation $x\sim y \iff y \text { is a (non-zero) scalar multiple of } x$ in the set of nonzero vectors $\mathbb{F}_q^r-\{0\}$ is an equivalence, and $cx=c'x \iff c=c'$ by cancellation law in $\mathbb{F}_q$. Therefore there are equally sized equivalence classes and there are $\frac{q^r -1}{q-1}$ of them, which is an integer.

Now is there a way in elementary arithmetic showing that $\frac{q^r -1}{q-1}$ is an integer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $x^n-1$ is divisible by $x-1$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579790/prove-xn-1-is-divisible-by-x-1-by-induction). It has nothing to do with primes.

Comment: Yes, look up the identity for $A^n-B^n$.

Comment: It is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-is-an-bn-divisible-by-a-b), that $a^n-b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$.

Comment: Great! Such an elementary identity I overlooked. Thanks all.